# How to retrieve helm release manifest via terraform helm_release resource?

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to retrieve the deployed manifest and metadata information using the terraform
"helm_release" resource

```
Metadata values are coming out nicely however its failing in getting the manifest

Sample code:
`output "show_release_md" {
value=helm_release.testdeploy.metadata
}`   -- This works
```

`output "show_release_manifest" { value=helm_release.testdeploy.manifest }`  - Manifest fails

```
Unsupported attribute. This object has no argument,nested block or exported attributes named 
"manifest"

Any ideas?
```

Answer (score 2):

You must enable the `manifest` feature flag in `experiments` block of the Helm provider first. For reference see the Helm provider [experiments block documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs#experiments) and [helm_release attribute reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#attributes-reference).

e.g.

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    config_path = "~/.kube/config"
  }
  experiments {
    manifest = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. Tried adding experiments and I am getting below error

Error: Unsupported block type
17:24:54  
17:24:54    on main.tf line 26, in provider "helm":
17:24:54    26:   experiments {
17:24:54  
17:24:54  Blocks of type "experiments" are not expected here.

sample code:

`provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   =  xxxx
    token.                = xxxxx
    
  }
  version = "2.0.2"
  experiments {
     manifest = true
  }
}`

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi All, Tried to remove the version = 2.0.2 and then the manifest feature started working . Thanks a lot ...